# Initialize Objective-C NSDictionary from c++ std::map

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, dictionary, nsdictionary

Is there a clever non-brute-force way to initialize an NSDictionary using the contents of an std::map?  FWIW, in my particular case, both the keys and the values of the std::map are std::string objects.  Thanks.

Comment: I don't think so; you're probably going to need to iterate the `map` and add the key/value pairs to the `NSMutableDictionary`.

Comment: That's what I've done.  I haven't found anything slick, nor can I imagine such a thing anyway.